# How do I find the asymptote of $y= -\tan(x+\pi/4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$y= -\tan(x+\pi/4).$$
How do I find the asymptote of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to find asymptotes of $$y = -\tan \left (x + \frac{\pi}{4} \right).$$

It is well-known that the $\tan$ function is undefined whenever $\cos(x) = 0$, which happens at $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$ for integer $k$.

Hence, we must have: $$x + \frac{ \pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k.$$

Simplifying, we get: $$x = \pi k + \frac{ \pi}{4}.$$

Thus, the asymptotes are $$x = \pi k + \frac{\pi}{4}$$ for integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I wouldn't answer, because the OP didn't show work.  But since another answer has already been given ...

Alternative approach

> $$y= -\tan(x+\pi/4).$$
> How do I find the asymptote of this?

Use that

- $\tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b)}{1 - \tan(a)\tan(b)},$
- $\tan(\pi/4) = 1$
- $\tan(x) = 1 \iff x \in \{\pi/4, 5\pi/4\}$, within a modulus of $2\pi$.

$$y = - \tan(x + \pi/4) = - \frac{\tan(x) + 1}{1 - \tan(x)}.$$

For an asymptote, it is *sufficient* that the denominator $= 0$ and the numerator $\neq 0$.  Sufficiency refers to the fact that when the numerator and denominator are **both** $(0)$, then the situation is unclear.  In this problem, no such complication is present.

Therefore, it is immediate that (within a modulus of $2\pi$), the asymptotes occur at $\{\pi/4, 5\pi/4\}.$

Comment: angle addition is a neat approach! That's a very nice and elegant finish.

Comment: @sfs2007 thanks